# How to Set Regular Expression for Nginx Location Block and Proxy Pass?

Tags: nginx, routing, regex, proxypass

I would like to ask about some configurations for Nginx; **How to setup regular expression in Nginx location block?** this is my configuration

```
location ~ ^/web/api/v1/([A-Za-z]+) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/$1;
}
```

So, the use case for this config is when i type `localhost/web/api/v1/apple` it will routed to `localhost:5000/apple`, `localhost/web/api/v1/pineapple` it will routed to `localhost:5000/pineapple`, and so on. Note: the apple and pineapple only example path name.

Thank You

Comment: Have you encountered a problem with the above? You should place a `$` on the end of the regular expression, as `$1` should contain the entire tail of the URI.

Comment: Hi Richard, yes i encountered error 502, i am still confuse how to handle this challenge

Comment: The error log should contain details.

Comment: Hi Richard, here is my error log: [error] 11296#4028: *1006 no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /web/api/v2/apple HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Comment: You should try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, or alternatively, define a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) which is usually required when the `proxy_pass` statement contains a variable.

Comment: Alright, i will do it first, i will let you know the result

Comment: Big thanks for you Richard, you've been very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer credit to @Richard Smith;

I am change the config become:

```
location ~ ^/web/api/v1/([A-Za-z]+)$ {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/$1;
}
```

localhost become 127.0.0.1